# Need an option to send camera output as video or frames in Unity3d 2017

Tags: unity, camera, video

Tools I've used in Unity 5.x are breaking my 2017 scene... and I do not see a way to output video or frames from Cinemachine (although I am trying to understand all of its features).

What is the best way in a mandatory C#/Unity 2017 workflow to capture camera output within Unity -- not a screen grab? No postprocessing needed... just frames!

In the past I have used Renderator Pro and VR Rocks, neither of which seem at the moment to support 2017 -- using deprecated code.

SOLUTION -- ROCK VR Does indeed work with Unity 2017... although not exactly the way I have modified it for 5.x.... but going back to stock import of resources and rebuilding works well.

Comment: Perhaps telling us how you were doing it in 5.x would better describe your requirements and might allow people to more easily give you an alternative that works in 2017.

Comment: Edited question with more info.

Comment: Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION -- ROCK VR Does indeed work with Unity 2017... although not exactly the way I have modified it for 5.x.... but going back to stock import of resources and rebuilding works well.